# Rewriting a query-string part as a path part using nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, http-basic-authentication

How do I rewrite URIs of the form

```
/one/two?path=three&foo=bar
```

to

```
/one/two/three?foo=bar
```

using nginx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
location ~ /one/two {
    if ($args ~ "path=([^&]+)&(.+)") {
        set $path $1;
        set $foo $2;
        rewrite ^/one/two "/one/two/$path?$foo?" permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your first post and append the entire content of `nginx.conf`.

Comment: Where did you put HTTP basic authentication section?